# Specific Role Commands for Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command for my Disc bot and I'm trying to make it role-related.

I've looked through other questions on this site but they're all in Python not JS; and on discord.js their examples are completely different from what I want to do. Everything up to this point works completely fine, it's just when it gets to this part (there isn't anything above or below this)

```js
if (message.member.roles.name == "Owner") {
    return message.reply("You can use this command!")
  }
  if (message.member.roles.name != "Owner") {
    return message.reply("Sorry, an error occurred.")
  }
```

I want to be able to see "You can use this command!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `message.member.roles` isn't going to be a single item, it will be a Collection of roles that the user has, so you need to search through the roles to check if the user has a role.

You can use the `.find()` function to see if the user has a role. It takes a function (in this case, a lambda function) that passes `r` (being the role), and checks if `r.name` is equal to your role (in this case, Owner)

```
if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Owner")){
  return message.reply("You can use this command!")
} else {
  return message.reply("Sorry, an error occurred.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is, you could get the role by their ID (as they probably don't change regularly) and then check if the user has that role.

```js
let ownerRole = message.guild.roles.get('123456789');
let moderatorRole = message.guild.roles.get('123456789');

if(msg.member.roles.has(ownerRole.id)) {
    // the user has the role
} else {
    // the user doesn't have the role.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write it like this. It can prevents many errors like "message.member.roles.name is not a function"

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
            const roleName = message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Owner")
            if (roleName) {
                return message.reply("You can use this command.")
            } else {
                return message.reply("Sorry, an error occured.")
            }
```

Comment: Only use code snippets for complete code that runs from the browser. Otherwise, use code blocks.